# Struggling with regex logic: how do I remove a param from a url query string?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, replace, logic

I'm comparing 2 URL query strings to see if they're equal; however, I want to ignore a specific query parameter (always with a numeric value) if it exists. So, these 2 query strings should be equal:

```
firstName=bobby&lastName=tables&paramToIgnore=2

firstName=bobby&lastName=tables&paramToIgnore=5
```

So, I tried to use a regex replace using the REReplaceNoCase function:

```
REReplaceNoCase(myQueryString, "&paramToIgnore=[0-9]*", "")
```

This works fine for the above example. I apply the replace to both strings and then compare. The problem is that I can't be sure that the param will be the last one in the string... the following 2 query strings should also be equal:

```
firstName=bobby&lastName=tables&paramToIgnore=2

paramToIgnore=5&firstName=bobby&lastName=tables
```

So, I changed the regex to make the preceding ampersand optional...  `"&?paramToIgnore=[0-9]*"`. But - these strings will still not be equal as I'll be left with an extra ampersand in one of the strings but not the other:

```
firstName=bobby&lastName=tables

&firstName=bobby&lastName=tables
```

Similarly, I can't just remove preceding *and* following ampersands (`"&?paramToIgnore=[0-9]*&?"`) as if the query param is in the *middle* of the string I'll strip one ampersand too many in one string and not the other - e.g.

```
firstName=bobby&lastName=tables&paramToIgnore=2

firstName=bobby&paramToIgnore=5&lastName=tables
```

will become

```
firstName=bobby&lastName=tables

firstName=bobbylastName=tables
```

I can't seem to get my head around the logic of this... Can anyone help me out with a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't be sure of the order the parameters appear i would recommend, that you don't compare them by the string itsself.

I recommend splitting the string up like this:

```
String stringA = "firstName=bobby&lastName=tables&paramToIgnore=2";
String stringB = "firstName=bobby&lastName=tables&paramToIgnore=5";

String[] partsA = stringA.split("&");
String[] partsB = stringB.split("&");
```

Then go through arrays and make the paramToIgnore somehow euqal:

```
for(int i = 0; i < partsA.length; i++)
{
  if(partsA[i].startsWith("paramToIgnore"){
   partsA[i] = "IgnoreMePlease";
  }
}

for(int j = 0; j < partsB.length; j++)
{
  if(partsB[i].startsWith("paramToIgnore"){
   partsB[i] = "IgnoreMePlease";
  }
}
```

Then you can sort and compare the arrays to see if they are equal:

```
Arrays.sort(partsA);
Arrays.sort(partsB);
boolean b = Arrays.equals(partsA, partsB);
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible to make this more compact and give it a better performance. But with comparing strings like you do, you somehow alsways have to care about the order of your parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [QueryStringDeleteVar](http://cflib.org/udf/QueryStringDeleteVar) UDF on cflib to remove the query string variables you want to ignore from both strings, then compare them.

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks... (Why on earth doesn't coldfusion have any list delete functions?!)

Comment: It has ListDeleteAt. In your case you would use the position and & as the delimiter http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d88.html

Comment: is that new to coldfusion 9? I don't seem to see it listed in the CF 8 docs, which is what we're using...

Comment: @froadie no, its been in CF for as long as I have used it (version 5) here is the URL to the version 8 docs for it http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_08.html

Answer (score 0):

Make it in two steps:

1. first remove your param, as you described in example
2. then remove ampersand which is left at the begining or the end of query with separate regex, or any double/triple/... ampersands in the middle of the query

Answer (score 0):

How about having an 'or' in the RegEx to match an ampersand at the start or the end?

```
&paramToIgnore=[0-9]*|paramToIgnore=[0-9]*&
```

Seems to do the job when testing in [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com)

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to:

REReplaceNoCase(myQueryString, "&?paramToIgnore=[0-9]+", "")

plus instead of star should capture 1 or more of the preceding matched characters. It won't match anything but 0-9 so if there is another parameter after that it'll stop when it can't match any more digits.

Alternatively, you could use:

REReplaceNoCase(myQueryString, "&?paramToIgnore=[^&]", "")

This will match anything but an ampersand. It will cover the case if the parameter exists but there is no value; which is probably something you'd want to account for.